# Windows 10: separate taskbar buttons from minimzed windows

Tags: windows, taskbar

Is it possible to separate the taskbar buttons from minimized windows in Windows 10? So it should look like this? So the buttons must stay always in the left part and the minimized windows on the right. The "Never combine" options does not do this.(ugly [example](https://www.tenforums.com/attachments/tutorials/178064d1519257281-enable-disable-grouping-taskbar-buttons-windows-never_combine.png?s=432c64eb26a45d518ecf56f65c9a469d))

This is what I want,  photo is from my actual Windows 7, don't remember how I did it, the installation is 5 years old:
[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3cS6.png)

Answer (score 0):

Right-click your taskbar, select "Taskbar Settings" and change the option "Combine taskbar buttons" to "Never".

The result looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wp1WV.png).

Comment: Nope, it still looks ugly, it seems that a new toolbar must be added named "Quick Launch", I managed to fix it by using Microsoft's link: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start-win_taskbar/add-quick-launch-toolbar-to-taskbar-in-windows-10/7c365da5-1d58-4c0f-bffe-afa1d3af006d